# I want to write a query where I can select only particular rows and want to ignore some different rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a table where BrandId is repeating multiple times in a table with different statuses like **pending** and **Running**.
I want the rows where status is only pending. If any BrandId whose status is pending as well as running, then we don't want this in the output, I want to ignore these BrandId and don't want that row in the output.

[image: Sample Input Table Data]

I only want those BrandId whose status is only pending.

Can anyone tell me about the query to get the required result?

[image: Sample output data that we want]

Comment: Are "prending" and "Running" the only statuses you have?  Do you have another table `brands`?

Answer (score 0):

Use not exists to filter those records which only have pending like below:

```
SELECT distinct ID, BRANDID, STATUS FROM TABLE1 A WHERE STATUS = 'pending'
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1 B WHERE A.ID = B.ID AND A.BRANDID = B.BRANDID AND B.STATUS = 'Running');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select brandid, max(status)
from tab
group by brandid
having max(status) = min(status) -- only one status exists 
   and max(status) = 'pending'   -- and it's 'pending'
```

If there's only 'pending' and 'running':

```
select brandid, max(status)
from tab
group by brandid
having max(status) = 'pending' --  no 'running'
```

You might want to add `id` to `group by`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` for brands with `running` status

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (
    select 1
    from table 
    where status = 'Running'
      and brandId = t.brandId 
)
and status = 'pending'
```

Another approach using aggregation would be

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.brandId in (
    select brandId 
    from table 
    group by brandId 
    having sum(case when status = 'pending' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
       and sum(case when status = 'Running' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
)
```